# DB not updated on serializer.save()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to build a api for updating first and last name for my user. The api runs successfully but database is not updated which is the expected behavior

I have written the following API and trying to pass the patch request to it.

```
class UserSelfUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [UserPermissions, ]

    def update(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
        serializer = UserUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data,)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The serializer for the above request is:

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields: ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

The format in which I am trying to pass my request body is:

```
{
    "first_name": "A",
    "last_name": "B"
}
```

and this is how my model is defined:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

When running code with debug pointer results in the no database update but 200 status.

When running code without debug pointer results in 500 status code and following error message in response

> AssertionError at /user/me-edit
>   ("Creating a ModelSerializer without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute has been deprecated since 3.3.0, and is now disallowed. Add an explicit fields = '**all**' to the UserUpdateSerializer serializer.",)

Comment: The error doesn't match the code you provided. Double check that you don't define another `UserUpdateSerializer`

Comment: for updating an object use **get** not **filter**

Comment: Thanks @c.grey It was the only mistake I was doing.

Comment: But note you don't need to do a query at all because `request.user` is *already* the User object.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resides in the serializer, and concretely, inside this part of the code:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields: ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

Fields are also a variable defined using =, so the code should look like:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

That will help you on solving that AssertionError.